# Need to solving 2nd order nonlinear ode.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, problem-solving

I need to solve the ordinary differential equation for $g(z)$ $$g''(z)=\frac{zg(z)}{3}+bg(z)^3 ,$$
where $z$ is independent variable and $b$ is constant. Can anyone please suggest anything?

Comment: **HINT:** Use numeric  to **solve**.

Comment: I need only an analytic solution and moreover, there is no boundary condition given.

Comment: Alternatively to numerical methods, you may be interested by semi-analytical solutions obtained by [perturbation methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory).

Comment: Can you provide some steps for particular this problem sir?